# On-screen CAPS LOCK indicator

Tags: windows, capslock

On my Acer laptop if I hit <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> it will pop up an OSD-like message saying something like "CAPS LOCK ON/OFF".

I find this very useful functionality - is there a generic freeware utility that can do this?

Edit: Here's the kind of OSD that Borek seems to mean. The is an power cable notification on my Asus laptop. Something similar for caps lock would be nice.

[image: Asus Power OSD]

Comment: I know this is old and I can't add my answer because the issue is closed. But I do have an answer, I followed this video and it worked on my HP desktop even if it was built for Acer laptop haha https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy2DaebGi8E&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of utilities similar to this. I've usually recommended the (appropriately named) [**Caps Lock**](http://www.georgejopling.co.uk/capslock/capslock.html) utility by George Jopling.

The indicator in the tray is unobtrusive and it works for caps or num lock. You can also have a sound played when the status of the keys are changed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you would like a sound notification, Windows has a feature called "ToggleKeys" built in that can be enabled in keyboard options.

Comment: I've came across this utility but it doesn't seem to have On-screen display which is a requirement.

Comment: Your system tray isn't on screen? Or do you just want the big popup like notify-osd provides?

Comment: The OP reads as wanting the big popup, yes.  And besides, tray icons AREN'T always visible.  What if you set your taskbar to autohide?  What if you have a full-screen app that covers it?

Comment: @Shin thats why I asked :)

Comment: Shinrai is right. On Acer laptops the CAPS LOCK notification looks like if you open a menu on some LCD display - it doesn't even use the Windows look and feel, it may be that Acer's driver is handling that, I don't know.

Comment: it's thanks to a piece of software called LaunchManager